# How to build with clang on Github Actions for Windows without hardcoding paths?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a project that locally builds fine out of the box with VS Community 2022 using the LLVM and cmake components. I would like to add this Windows build to Github actions CI.

Locally, VS Code's cmake-tools automagically configures the appropriate "kit" to configure cmake to use clang.exe to build the project. The kit added by cmake-tools is as follows:

```
  {
    "name": "Clang 13.0.0 (GNU CLI) for MSVC 17.1.32228.430 (Visual Studio Community 2022 Release - amd64)",
    "visualStudio": "e9d6c456",
    "visualStudioArchitecture": "amd64",
    "compilers": {
      "C": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang.exe",
      "CXX": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\Llvm\\x64\\bin\\clang.exe"
    }
  },
```

I have a similar build working on Github Actions with the following setup:

```
      - name: Configure
        run: cmake . -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/PROGRAM FILES/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO/2022/ENTERPRISE/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang.exe" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe"
```

Here I've had to hardcode the path to both the compiler and Ninja for cmake to find them. Is there a way to do this that is more flexible?

Comment: You may try adding the platform toolset to your CMake command, e.g. `cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -T clang-cl` see Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=msvc-170). Don't know if that's doable with ninja.

Comment: @vre I could care less about Ninja, but I am explicitly not targeting `clang-cl` as I don't care to support MS-style flags in the build. There are no  predefined MS Build targets for the standard `clang` frontend.

What I'm asking is if there's anyway to port cmake-tools behavior of "discovering" the available compilers and using the right one, instead of the incredibly fragile hardcode that won't survive a VS update or Github Actions image change. No other OS requires such hardcoded paths.

Comment: How did you install MSVC in GitHub actions ?

Comment: @Tanishq-Banyal It's preinstalled on the Windows image